# Backing Analysis Services cube daily with a datestamp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, cube, olap-cube

I am creating a job that runs every day to back up an SSAS database that I have. Here is the Analysis Services Command for that

Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine"

`<Object>`
`<DatabaseID>PipeLine</DatabaseID>`
`</Object>`
`<File>C:\DBBackup\PipeLine.abf</File>`
 `</Backup>`

I don't write to overwrite my backup daily. Could any one please let me know how to add a date-stamp to my backup file.

If not, I have backup-devices for each day(eg, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday etc). Is there a way I could check for the day and store the backup in the respective backup device for the day

Please help me

Comment: From where is the above backup XMLA script executed? From a SQL Server agent job? As A pre-run script from a backup batch? From a PowerShell script? From somewhere else ...?

Comment: It is created as a pre-run script from the backup batch

Answer (score 0):

XMLA itself does not offer any date logic to be used for the file name. Hence, you would have to implement that in the environment calling the script. I. e. you will have to generate the XMLA backup script with a different file name each time you call it.

If you are using a Windows batch file, you could use a line like

```
for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`date /t`) do echo "<Backup xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine'<Object> <DatabaseID>PipeLine</DatabaseID></Object><File>C:\DBBackup\PipeLine%%b.abf</File></Backup>"
```

replacing `echo` with the call to execute the XMLA. please note that if you do not execute this within a batch file, but directly in a command line, you should use one percent sign for the variable `b` instead of two, as explained here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: Hi, I am little confused. I will tell you clearly what I did so far. 1. Connected to Analysis Services, right clicked the cube database that I want to back it up daily. Clicked on Backup, backup database screen appears and there is an option to script (Script Action to New Query Window/Script Action to File/Script Action to ClipBoard). I clicked on Script Action to New Query Window and got the script on  xmla window

Comment: @user3063530 I am confused a bit as well. I understood from your question and the answer to my comment that you have an automated job running that backs up the *.abf files to e. g. a tape drive, and before running this main backup, the job calls a batch file which runs the XMLA script to backup the AS database to the *.abf file. And I understood your question was how you can change the process to get the current date into the file name. If this is not your requirement, please edit your question to more clearly state what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I need more details on how to "loop" this thing, because obviously the "for /f..." string will NOT work under XMLA's query window. a batch file is too 1980's to consider use in the 21st century. Perhaps a more modern SSIS script with SQL Agent will pull a cleaner outcome.